# Word file locked whenever program crashes manually or by some issue

Tags: asp.net, file-locking

I am reading one word file for that first object of word is created then word file is opened.

What problem i am facing is whenever file is opened by word object if after that program crashes or end by task manager manually then that word file locks and unable to delete that file.. For that i need to kill winword.exe process from the task manager to release that process.

My code is:

```
Word.Application word = new Word.Application();
......//Some code
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = word.Documents.Open(filename);
...//some code
try{
                doc.Save();
                ((Word._Document)doc).Close();
}
finally{
                   ((Word._Application)word).Quit(Word.WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges);
}
```

If program crashes then this line
((Word._Application)word).Quit(Word.WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges);
not executed causing file lock.

Any solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

The Office PIA (primary interop assemblies) is a set of unmanaged wrappers around the Office applications. Your code is effectively opening Word and using it just like a regular (human) user. If Word closes prematurely it may leave the file locked. You can't control that.

Take a look at the OpenXML SDK.  Word files are actually XML documents, and you can work with them directly without using the PIA COM interops.  OpenXML is much, much faster than PIA, and much more stable.

[Microsoft OpenXML SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk)

Comment: thanks @Qubert, but using OpenXML SDK will be major code and functionality change, So is any other solution is possible

Comment: OpenXML has a bunch of different ways listed to install it... none of which work or have any details on using them.  Typical of MS to reinvent stuff, and then drop the ball.